# django multiply db schemas on postgres

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, database-schema

The question I'm asking is, is there posibilty that Django can redirect user to specific schema in database.

User is created in registration form on default django table : **aut_user**, which
is applied to default database in setup.py file.

When user is created I just wanna say in Django, for new created user create schema and use that schema only for this user on login.

I was looking all around for this answer so I didin't find any, can you give me some tip or maybe you have come across with this problem?

Comment: There is a Django project that implements something similar at https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas

Comment: Yea I've read that article, but my problem is how to add generic schema when user is created, after that when user go on loginpage and after success login he works in his schema.